# sbt sharing bashScriptExtraDefines in several sub modules

Tags: scala, sbt

I have project with several sub packages. 
For part of them I have in the build.sbt the same bashScriptExtraDefines.
I want to define this bashScriptExtraDefines in one place and "include" it in the sub package.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In `build.sbt` toplevel:

```
val ourBashScriptExtraDefines = Seq(
  // In some cases you might want to use ++=, e.g. for stacking settings
  bashScriptExtraDefines := List(...)  // Docs for sbt-native-packager say "List"
)
```

And then when defining a project in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val project1 = (project in file("path/to/project1"))
  .settings(ourBashScriptExtraDefines ++ Seq(
    //project-specific settings
  ))
```